# Windows prevents me to press lowercase B

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have this weird problem that started today. Windows 7 does not register the lowercase <kbd>b</kbd> to be pressed on my keyboard.

It works at the login screen and on other computers so I know that the actual hardware is not faulty. Uppercase <kbd>B</kbd> works though and I have no idea what this problem could originate from.

My keyboard is a Corsair Gaming K95 RGB and i have the latest firmware and software (Corsair utility engine). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the lowercase 'B' work in the virtual keyboard on Windows 7

Comment: Do you have any keyboard mapping tools?  Does it occur in safe mode

Comment: lowercase works with the virtual keyboard. I cannot enter safe mode at the moment so i dont know. I use the corsair utility engine as the keyboard software. And i did not find any new keybindings in the program.

Comment: It works now! It appears that i had downloaded an soundswitcher software of some sort. I removed it and i can finally use my lower case  "b"  again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a keyboard hook from some software.

The easiest way to identify the source is exiting (or in worst case killing) the software, one-by-one. First, prepare your computer for shutdown (finish all work).

Software from vendors with high reputation rarely causes such issues so start with software

- running under your account
- coming from not-so-trusted vendor

User [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to display list of running stuff and add **Company Name** column to the table. This will help you quickly find those few processes which are least trusted. Start terminating these.

You can also right-click running process and select **Check VirusTotal** item to get the process hash checked by 50+ antivirus products. Very helpful sometimes.